# How do you add an android studio project to an existing repository on GitHub?

Tags: android, git, github

I know how to add a project to a new repository, but I have an already existing repository and I am unsure how to sync my android studio project with this repository.

Also, the existing repository is part of an organization on GitHub I belong to.

Comment: I don't want to create a repo though. I want to add the project to an existing repo if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can add code to existing repository, by adding the Github repo URL to list of existing remote with a new alias as below:

```
git remote add <alias-name> <repo-url>
```

Then you can push code to the repo as below:

```
git push -u <alias-name> <branch-to-push>
```

Comment: I tried the first command but it is giving me the error message: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: In that case you have not initialised it as a git repo.